# Add items into a "class" List java

Tags: java, list

I don't know how to properly ask this, but I created a list based on a class, and now I want to add variables to this list, now In c# I would do something like this:

```
listitem.add( new Item(){Name = name, Cat = cat});
```

How can I accomplish this in java?

Comment: listitem.add(new Item(name, cat)); // assuming that you have proper constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java, you would create a constructor in `Item` that takes `name` and `cat`.

```
public class Item {
  private String name;
  private Object cat;

  public Item(String name, Object cat) {
    this.name = name;
    this.cat = cat;
  }
 ...
}
```

Then you would construct the `Item`s like so:

```
listitem.add( new Item(name, cat));
```

(Note that without knowing what type `cat` is, I assigned it the type `Object` above.)

Answer (score 0):

For your particular example you can use

```
listitem.add(new Item(name, cat));
```

I would recommend reading one of the java collection tutorials to get the feel how the syntax differs from a language that you are familiar with (i.e. c#). [Here is one tutorial example](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-collections/list.html).